# Is my index too expensive to maintain?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, index-tuning

I just indexed a view that returns 126 millions rows.

There's a process that uses this view to update rows using a trigger and it's by far the most expensive process in my database.

I'm monitoring this new index usage DMVs and I'm getting a strong feeling that there's too much processing power involved in maintaining this index to balance it's usefulness.

Running the query bellow, it tells me that every 2-5 seconds there's one user seek on this index. During the same timeframe there will have been around 250-1000 user updates. Since it's creation 15 minutes ago, USER_SEEKS=386 while USER_UPDATES=102 876.

Is there a magic ratio where you can safely say it's not worth it to maintain such an index ?

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(S.[OBJECT_ID]) AS [OBJECT NAME], 
       I.[NAME] AS [INDEX NAME], 
       USER_SEEKS, 
       USER_SCANS, 
       USER_LOOKUPS, 
       USER_UPDATES 
FROM   SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS AS S 
       INNER JOIN SYS.INDEXES AS I ON I.[OBJECT_ID] = S.[OBJECT_ID] AND I.INDEX_ID = S.INDEX_ID 
WHERE  OBJECTPROPERTY(S.[OBJECT_ID],'IsUserTable') = 1
       AND S.database_id = DB_ID()
       and I.NAME ='<index_name_goes_here>'
```

Comment: I will ask the question how bad my seek will perform without the index, is that acceptable for my use case?

Comment: In my case I would say it is perfectly acceptable. Honestly I don't know why this task doesn't run only twice or even once a day... I have no idea what business requirement it meets by running continuously, my guess is as good as yours.

Comment: The question you usually want to ask is how bad the index actually slows down DUIs. If there's very little overhead, and it's helping with your read queries, then the extra maintenance may be worth it.

Comment: If you don't know why it's running continuously, find out!  It's entirely possible it doesn't need to run that often, and you can work to reduce the frequency... or eliminate it entirely, if it's actually completely unused (John asked for it 7 years ago; he left the company 6 years ago, no-one's looked at the results since).

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords I'm seriously laughin at this "John" story right there. If you knew the sheer ammount of John's remnants I'm dealing with on a daily basis you'd be amazed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a magic ratio where you can safely say it's not worth it to maintain such an index ?**

There is not a magic number that exist. You might have an index that is used rarely (compare to number of updates) but supporting that query is important for your business/users.

It is a call that only you can make based on your business/user requirement.

If you want to test, do not drop the index. You can disable the index that way your metadata about the index is preserved. Here is a good post about that.

[Disabling vs. Dropping Indexes](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/disabling-vs-dropping-indexes/) by Jes Borland.